# anchor in HTML 5

Tags: html, anchor

In the [HTML5 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) it says

```
Some elements, such as <a>, <cite> and
<menu> have been changed, redefined or
standardised
```

Does this mean the anchor tag? If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change with the  tag is that it's now allowed to contain block level elements, where before it was only allowed to contain inline elements.